# Where can I get a replacement battery door for a Sony NEX camera?

Tags: repair, sony, diy, sony-nex

Could anybody tell me from where can I order a spare door for the battery of my camera, a Sony NEX F3. I need to replace it as it was broken,  and I cannot find it online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a mere mortal, you probably can't. Selling parts is a hassle, and additionally most companies protect their authorized service centers in this way. So, your choices are probably one of:

1. Send the camera in for repair. If the door came of as part of normal use, I would expect that to be covered under warranty.
2. Look out for broken cameras of the same model on eBay or other online auction sites. People sometimes try to get a few dollars out of electronics that don't work, and maybe you will get lucky there.